# Does anyone know how Group By can work with paginate in CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-1.2

I have the following segment of code in which I want to Group everything by the Release.id since I am getting a lot of duplicates. Even though I have a DISTINCT, it completely gets ignored.

Can someone guide me in the right direction?

```
$this->Release->recursive = 0;
    $this->paginate['Release']['joins'] =
                   array(
                    array(
                        'table' => 'game_potential_amazon_matches',
                        'alias' => 'PotentialAmazonMatch',
                        'type' => 'inner',
                        'conditions' =>
                        array(
                            'PotentialAmazonMatch.release_id = Release.id'
                            ),'fields' => array('DISTINCT Release.id')
                           )
                    );
    $this->set('releases', $this->paginate('Release'));






RELEASE TABLE
id
name
asin


MATCHES TABLE
date
asin
release_id
```

The matches table has a one to many relationship with Release table. I just want a single release.

Comment: This seems to be the code snippet for the table to be joined. Could you pass the code for the table this is joined with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are now defining `'fields' => array('DISTINCT Release.id')` 
in array
 `$this->paginate['Release']['joins'].`

Try to place it after conditions in `$this->paginate['Release'].`

Comment: I tried this: $this->paginate['Release']['conditions'] = array('fields' => array('DISTINCT Release.id'));

Comment: No, try `$this->paginate['Release']['fields'] = array('DISTINCT Release.id');`